# Expandable cell with dynamic data (swift)

Tags: swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let lblTitle : UILabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel
    lblTitle.text = (deptId[indexPath.row] as? String)! + "     " + (deptDesc[indexPath.row] as? String)!
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        for i in 0...deptProfile.count-1{
            let deptmentProfile = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,44+height,400,41))
            deptmentProfile.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            height = height+41
            deptmentProfile.setTitle(deptProfile[i] as! String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            deptmentProfile.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            deptmentProfile.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left
            deptmentProfile.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            deptmentProfile.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 0); //margin to the left
            cell.addSubview(deptmentProfile)
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    }
    return cell
}
```

Question: since my expanded data is dynamic,(In coding)deptProfrile is dynamic. How can i clear the cell content? it seems the subview will remain to the cell every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that the cell is reused, so, you have not coded for the `else` case for that `if`: `if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath)`. You should provide the code for UI for that `else`.

You can give the estimated cell height for the tableview, so it will expand the cell for you.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath){
        var cellHeight = 100 // Assume this is the height when deptProfile.count = 0
        cellHeight = cellHeight + 44 * deptProfile.count
        return cellHeight
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```